# Different in EclipseLink vs Hibernate Persistent Context?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, jhipster

I am testing the differences between Hibernate and Eclipselink and noticed that EclipseLink persists the data even when there is no persist action.

E.g. tested with jhipster. What could be the cause of it because both Hibernate and EclipseLink is an implementation of JPA. With the same codes, the outcomes are different. Does anyone have any ideas?

Below data seems different for both implementation.

**Hibernate**. Department name: XYZ --> Click View --> Department name: test1234 --> Click Back --> Department name: XYZ

**Eclipselink**. Department name: XYZ --> Click View --> Department name: test1234 --> Click Back --> Department name: test1234 --> Click Edit --> Department name: test1234 (remains the name)

**Hibernate**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<Department> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Department : {}", id);
        Optional<Department> d = departmentRepository.findById(id);
        d.ifPresent(user -> {
            user.setDepartmentName("test1234");

        });
        return departmentRepository.findById(id);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DepartmentResource {
    @GetMapping("/departments/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Department> getDepartment(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Department : {}", id);
        Optional<Department> department = departmentService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(department);
    }
}

**application-dev.yml**

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    tech.jhipster: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    com.mycompany.myapp: DEBUG

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password:
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "com.mycompany.myapp.repository" })
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {}
```

Test scenario.

1. Entities > Department [Department name is XYZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z61iu.png)
2. Click View.[Department name now changed to test1234](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euWSQ.png)
3. Click Back. [Department name remains as XYZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z61iu.png) (**Current behavior: XYZ: Expected behaviour: XYZ**)

**EclipseLink**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<Department> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Department : {}", id);
        Optional<Department> d = departmentRepository.findById(id);
        d.ifPresent(user -> {
            user.setDepartmentName("test1234");

        });
        return departmentRepository.findById(id);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DepartmentResource {
    @GetMapping("/departments/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Department> getDepartment(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Department : {}", id);
        Optional<Department> department = departmentService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(department);
    }
}

**application-dev.yml**

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    tech.jhipster: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    com.mycompany.myapp: DEBUG

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password: 
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      eclipselink.target-database: MySQL
      eclipselink.weaving: static
      eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode: auto
      #eclipselink-persistence-context.persist-on-commit: false
      eclipselink.flush-clear.cache: merge
      eclipselink.logging.level: ALL
      eclipselink.query-results-cache: false
      eclipselink.cache.shared.default: false

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "com.mycompany.myapp.repository" })
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    protected DatabaseConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties,
                                    ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManagerProvider) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManagerProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, "none");
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    }
```

Test scenario.

1. Entities > Department
   [Department name is XYZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuKFI.png)
2. Click View.[Department name now changed to test1234](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euWSQ.png)
3. Click Back. [Department name changed to as test1234](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuKFI.png) (**Current behavior: test1234, Expected behavior: XYZ**)
4. Click Edit. [Department name not changed and remains as test1234](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuKFI.png)  (**Current behavior: test1234, Expected behavior: XYZ**)

Comment: Did you check transaction begin/end in logs? Could it be an issue of transaction propagation between the enclosing `@Transactional` and the inner `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`

Comment: readOnly is only considered by HIbernate

Comment: Is the data actually persisted in the database, or is your testing just reusing the same entityManager context? EclipseLink does have a read-only concept that Spring might be using - but it likely works differently from Hibernate. Entities marked read-only are not allowed to be changed, as what is returned is the instance that EclipseLink would use for comparison - it just doesn't make an instance with change tracking enabled (or make copies for comparisons if using deferred change tracking). That, or your changes are getting into the DB, which is Spring committing your transaction.

Comment: the data is persisted after setting the department name.

Comment: I am seeing that static meta model generate as 

@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.7.9.v20210604-rNA", date="not important (ignore it))

The value should be value="org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor" right? Whats wrong?